# std::endl is of unknown type when overloading operator<<

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

I overloaded operator <<

```
template <Typename T>
UIStream& operator<<(const T);

UIStream my_stream;
my_stream << 10 << " heads";
```

Works but:

```
my_stream << endl;
```

Gives compilation error:

> error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'UIStream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

What is the work around for making `my_stream << endl` work?

Comment: Without knowing anything about UIStream, it's a bit difficult to comment.

Comment: And yet, you found a way. :)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`std::endl` is a function and `std::cout` utilizes it by implementing `operator<<` to take  a function pointer with the same signature as `std::endl`.

In there, it calls the function, and forwards the return value.

Here is a code example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyStream
{
    template <typename T>
    MyStream& operator<<(const T& x)
    {
        std::cout << x;

        return *this;
    }


    // function that takes a custom stream, and returns it
    typedef MyStream& (*MyStreamManipulator)(MyStream&);

    // take in a function with the custom signature
    MyStream& operator<<(MyStreamManipulator manip)
    {
        // call the function, and return it's value
        return manip(*this);
    }

    // define the custom endl for this stream.
    // note how it matches the `MyStreamManipulator`
    // function signature
    static MyStream& endl(MyStream& stream)
    {
        // print a new line
        std::cout << std::endl;

        // do other stuff with the stream
        // std::cout, for example, will flush the stream
        stream << "Called MyStream::endl!" << std::endl;

        return stream;
    }

    // this is the type of std::cout
    typedef std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > CoutType;

    // this is the function signature of std::endl
    typedef CoutType& (*StandardEndLine)(CoutType&);

    // define an operator<< to take in std::endl
    MyStream& operator<<(StandardEndLine manip)
    {
        // call the function, but we cannot return it's value
        manip(std::cout);

        return *this;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    MyStream stream;

    stream << 10 << " faces.";
    stream << MyStream::endl;
    stream << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully this gives you a better idea of how these things work.

Comment: Please leave a comment when you down vote so I can improve my answer.

Comment: I did not downvote, but there is an important detail missing here: std::endl is not a function but a templated function. This means that if you try to define a generic manipulator accepting operator<< overload as: `template <typename T> mystream& operator<<( T& (*fp)(T&) )` (this signature would accept all STL `basic_stream<>`, `ios_base` and `basic_ios<>` manipulators) the compiler will not be able to match std::endl against the template, as it is a template in itself and it cannot define what T means.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me in answering another question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196155

Comment: Why the `typedef CoutType` instead of just using `ostream`?

Answer (score 38):

The problem is that `std::endl` is a function template, as your operator `<<`
is. So when you write:

```
my_stream << endl;
```

you'll like the compiler to deduce the template parameters for the operator
as well as for `endl`. This isn't possible.

So you have to write additional, non template, overloads of operator `<<` to
work with manipulators. Their prototype will look like:

```
UIStream& operator<<(UIStream& os, std::ostream& (*pf)(std::ostream&));
```

(there are two others, replacing `std::ostream` by `std::basic_ios<char>` and
`std::ios_base`, which you have also to provide if you want to allow all
manipulators) and their implementation will be very similar to the one of
your templates.  In fact, so similar that you can use your template for
implementation like this:

```
typedef std::ostream& (*ostream_manipulator)(std::ostream&);
UIStream& operator<<(UIStream& os, ostream_manipulator pf)
{
   return operator<< <ostream_manipulator> (os, pf);
}
```

A final note, often writing a custom `streambuf` is often a better way to
achieve what one try to achieve applying to technique you are using.

Comment: +1 this is the same answer I provided yesterday. Unluckily it has been ignored. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133739/how-does-ofstream-or-ostream-type-cast-all-types-to-string/1134501#1134501

Comment: Actually I found the same solution, but I used a simpler function body: `pf(*this); return *this;`, but I add `op<<` as a member of my derived ostreamer class.

Answer (score 10):

I did this to solve my problem, here is part of my code:

```
    template<typename T> 
    CFileLogger &operator <<(const T value)
    {
        (*this).logFile << value;
        return *this;
    }
    CFileLogger &operator <<(std::ostream& (*os)(std::ostream&))
    {
        (*this).logFile << os;
        return *this;
    }
```

**Main.cpp**

```
int main(){

    CFileLogger log();    
    log << "[WARNINGS] " << 10 << std::endl;
    log << "[ERRORS] " << 2 << std::endl;
    ...
}
```

I got the reference in here http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/49590/

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 5):

See [here](http://www.horstmann.com/cpp/iostreams.html) for better ways of extending IOStreams. (A bit outdated, and tailored for VC 6, so you will have to take it with a grain of salt)

The point is that to make functors work (and endl, which both outputs "\n" and flushes is a functor) you need to implement the full ostream interface.

Answer (score 4):

The `std` streams are not designed to be subclassed as they have no virtual methods so I don't think you'll get too far with that. You can try aggregating a std::ostream to do the work though.

To make `endl` work you need to implement a version of `operator<<` that takes a pointer-to-function as that is how the manipulators such as `endl` are handled i.e.

```
UStream& operator<<( UStream&, UStream& (*f)( UStream& ) );
```

or

```
UStream& UStream::operator<<( UStream& (*f)( UStream& ) );
```

Now `std::endl` is a function that takes and returns a reference to a std::basic_ostream so that won't work directly with your stream so you'll need to make your own version which calls through to the `std::endl` version in your aggregated `std::iostream`.

Edit: Looks likes GMan's answer is better. He gets `std::endl` working too!

Comment: I will support this answer :P

Comment: Actually not. If you'd care to read the linked article from my article, you'd know how to make ALL functors work, not just those you explicitly implemented.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, with C++11 it is possible to overload `operator<<` for the type:

```
decltype(std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>)
```