# Why does compiler generate error?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Why does compiler generate error?

```
template<class T>
void ignore (const T &) {}

void f() {
   ignore(std::endl);
}
```

Compiler VS2008 gives the following error: `cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous`.

Comment: cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that problem is that `std::endl` is a template function and compiler cannot deduce template argument for `ignore` function.

```
template <class charT, class traits>
  basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl ( basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os );
```

To fix a problem you could write something like as follows:

```
void f() {
   ignore(std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>);
}
```

But you should know that you will pass pointer to function as argument, not result of function execution.

Answer (score 2):

std::endl is a function template. See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134388/stdendl-is-of-unknown-type-when-overloading-operator) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

> [In function 'void f()': Line 8: error:
>   no matching function for call to
>   'ignore(<unresolved overloaded
>   function type>)' compilation
>   terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.](http://codepad.org/FynoRVDU)

std::endl is not a class, its a function template.