# C++ stream as a parameter when overloading operator<<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stream, endl

I'm trying to write my own logging class and use it as a stream:

```
logger L;
L << "whatever" << std::endl;
```

This is the code I started with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class logger{
public:
    template <typename T>
    friend logger& operator <<(logger& log, const T& value);
};

template <typename T>
logger& operator <<(logger& log, T const & value) {
    // Here I'd output the values to a file and stdout, etc.
    cout << value;
    return log;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    logger L;
    L << "hello" << '\n' ; // This works
    L << "bye" << "alo" << endl; // This doesn't work
    return 0;
}
```

But I was getting an error when trying to compile, saying that there was no definition for operator<< (when using std::endl):

```
pruebaLog.cpp:31: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘operator<< [with T = char [4]](((logger&)((logger*)operator<< [with T = char [4]](((logger&)(& L)), ((const char (&)[4])"bye")))), ((const char (&)[4])"alo")) << std::endl’
```

So, I've been trying to overload operator<< to accept this kind of streams, but it's driving me mad. I don't know how to do it. I've been loking at, for instance, the definition of std::endl at the ostream header file and written a function with this header:

```
logger& operator <<(logger& log, const basic_ostream<char,char_traits<char> >& (*s)(basic_ostream<char,char_traits<char> >&))
```

But no luck. I've tried the same using templates instead of directly using char, and also tried simply using "const ostream& os", and nothing.

Another thing that bugs me is that, in the error output, the first argument for operator<< changes, sometimes it's a reference to a pointer, sometimes looks like a double reference...

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::endl is of unknown type when overloading operator<< ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134388/stdendl-is-of-unknown-type-when-overloading-operator)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`endl` is a strange beast. It isn't a constant value. It's actually, of all things, a function. You need a special override to handle the application of `endl`:

```
logger& operator<< (logger& log, ostream& (*pf) (ostream&))
{
  cout << pf;
  return log;
}
```

This accepts insertion of a function that takes an `ostream` reference and returns an `ostream` reference. That's what `endl` is.

**Edit:** In response to FranticPedantic's interesting question of "why can't the compiler deduce this automatically?". The reason is that if you delve yet deeper, `endl` is actually itself a *template* function. It's defined as:

```
template <class charT, class traits>
  basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl ( basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os );
```

That is, it can take any sort of `ostream` as its input and output. So the problem isn't that the compiler can't deduce that `T const &` could be a function pointer, but that it can't figure out *which* `endl` you meant to pass in. The templated version of `operator<<` presented in the question would accept a pointer to any function as its second argument, but at the same time, the `endl` template represents an *infinite* set of potential functions, so the compiler can't do anything meaningful there.

Providing the special overload of the `operator<<` whose second argument matches a *specific* instantiation of the `endl` template allows the call to resolve.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. 

Now that I see your solution, I find that my definition `basic_ostream<char,char_traits<char> >& (*s)(basic_ostream<char,char_traits<char> >&)` which is a generic version of ostream, wasn't working because it was defined "const". Once I've dropped the const, it's worked.

Comment: To me the real question remains, which is why can't the compiler deduce T as a function pointer and bind to it?

Answer (score 5):

`endl` is an IO manipulator, which is a functor that accepts a stream by reference, performs some operation on it, and returns that stream, also by reference. `cout << endl` is equivalent to `cout << '\n' << flush`, where `flush` is a manipulator that flushes the output buffer.

In your class, you just need to write an overload for this operator:

```
logger& operator<<(logger&(*function)(logger&)) {
    return function(*this);
}
```

Where `logger&(*)(logger&)` is the type of a function accepting and returning a `logger` by reference. To write your own manipulators, just write a function that matches that signature, and have it perform some operation on the stream:

```
logger& newline(logger& L) {
    return L << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This is more complicated than the accepted answer but an interesting approach nonetheless.

Comment: @FranticPedantic: Two sides of the same coin, really.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it is the **stream buffer** that encapsulates the underlying I/O mechanisim. The stream itself only encapsulates the conversions to string, and the I/O direction.

Thus you should be using one of the predefined stream classes, rather than making your own. If you have a new target you want your I/O to go to (like a system log), what you should be creating is your own *stream buffer* (derived from `std::streambuf`).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is your stream doesn't overload `operator<<` to accept a function that has the same type as `std::endl` as illustrated in this answer: [std::endl is of unknown type when overloading operator<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134388/stdendl-is-of-unknown-type-when-overloading-operator)