# Why does my own output stream class not work?

Tags: c++, class, stream, iostream, template-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [std::endl is of unknown type when overloading operator<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134388/stdendl-is-of-unknown-type-when-overloading-operator)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct OutputStream
{
    template<class T>
    OutputStream& operator <<(const T& obj)
    {
        cout << obj;

        return *this;
    }
};

OutputStream os;

int main()
{    
    os << 3.14159 << endl; // Compilation Failure!
}
```

The VC++ 2012 compiler complains:

> error C2676: binary '<<' : 'OutputStream' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Comment: You didn't define endl

Comment: Does T not apply to endl?

Comment: I thought it would apply, but the code does compile without endl.
I'll just wait for brighter guys to answer. :p

Comment: Well, since it's an exact duplicate... remove this?

Comment: I have voted to close this post of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the compiler cannot deduce the type of `T`, because [`std::endl`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/endl/) is a function template defined as

```
template <class charT, class traits>
  basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl ( basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os );
```

The way it is overcome in IOStreams is by providing an appropriate overload of `operator<<`:

```
OutputStream& operator <<(std::ostream& ( *pf )(std::ostream&))
{
  cout << pf;
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: Good answer! Concise and generic!