# Templates for cout input

Tags: c++, templates, stream, cout

I want to create a function that takes in anything that the `<<` operator for `std::cout` can handle. I have an example that breaks.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void my_print(const T &t) {
  std::cout << t;
}

int main() {
  my_print("hello\n"); // works
  my_print(4); // works
  my_print(std::endl); // compiler error
  return 0;
}
```

It also fails if I change to `void my_print(T t)`. The compiler error is

```
error: no matching function for call to 'my_print(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
note: candidate is
note: template<class T> void my_print(const T&)
```

Why can't the compiler resolve it when it sees that the argument `t` is being put into `cout`?

Is there any good way to fix this or do I have to manually provide the additional `<<` cases, e.g. `void my_print(ostream& (*pf)(ostream&));`

EDIT: I know `endl` is a function. Is the answer then that function types are not accepted as templates? Like I can't have `[T = ostream& (*)(ostream&)]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::endl is of unknown type when overloading operator<<](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134388/stdendl-is-of-unknown-type-when-overloading-operator)

Comment: It's because endl *isn't* a function...

Comment: @KerrekSB Huh? `ostream& operator<< (ostream& (*pf)(ostream&))` is what is invoked by `cout << endl`. This seems to indicate that `endl` is a function taking and returning an `ostream&`.

Comment: @Nick std::endl is indeed a function.

Comment: @Nick: It's a function *template* which can be instantiated to match that `ostream` overload. But that's not the same as being a function, as you've just experienced yourself.

Comment: It's not a _single_ function, most importantly (you have the same problem with non-templated overload sets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::endl` is actually a function template. You can read the full documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) or [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/). It is defined as:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

Edit: You can achieve what you want using this solution (which I vaguely adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1134467/401200))

```
#include <iostream>

// handles the other types
template <typename T>
void my_print(const T &t) {
  std::cout << t;
}

// alias a few things to make the prototypes readable
typedef std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > CoutType;
typedef CoutType& (*StandardEndLine)(CoutType&);

int main() {
  my_print("hello\n"); // works
  my_print(4); // works
  my_print((StandardEndLine)std::endl); // <- NOTE: there is an explicit cast
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not a function, that's a template.

Comment: Technically speaking it is called an IO manipulator. But it is "something that takes an argument and returns a value...", calling it a function is not far off...

Comment: The links to the documentation in my post list it as a function as well.