# How can I use my own abc::endl; here like in iostream

Tags: c++, iostream

When I try my own version I am getting

error C2039: 'endl' : is not a member of 'abc'
error C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier

Here is the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

//assume this class uses some proprietary logging system.  I just use the wrap the C
//output functions here but assume is a corporate log system
namespace abc {

   class log_stream
   {
   public:
      log_stream(const char* filename) {
         fp_ = fopen(filename, "w");
      }

      log_stream& operator<<(short val)          { if (fp_) { output_int(val); } return *this; }
      log_stream& operator<<(unsigned short val) { if (fp_) { output_int(val); } return *this; }
      log_stream& operator<<(int val)            { if (fp_) { output_int(val); } return *this; }
      log_stream& operator<<(unsigned int val)   { if (fp_) { output_int(val); } return *this; }
      log_stream& operator<<(long val)           { if (fp_) { output_int(val); } return *this; }
      log_stream& operator<<(unsigned long val)  { if (fp_) { output_int(val); } return *this; }
      log_stream& operator<<(const char* val)    { if (fp_) { output_string(val); } return *this; }
      inline log_stream& endl(log_stream& os)  { return os.endl(); }
      //etc
      log_stream& endl() {
         if(fp_)
            fputc('\n', fp_);
         return *this;
      }

   private:
      void output_int(long v) { fprintf(fp_, "%d", v); }
      void output_string(const char* s) { fprintf(fp_, "%s", s); }
      FILE* fp_;
   };
}  //namespace abc

int main() {
   abc::log_stream logger("myfile.txt");
   //error C2039: 'endl' : is not a member of 'abc', error C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
   logger << "number " << 3 << abc::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

If I add

```
inline log_stream& endl(log_stream& os)  { return os.endl(); }
```

inside the abc namespace (but outside the class, I then get

```
error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'abc::log_stream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Which is closer (I think) to solving, but not there yet.

UPDATE2.

Well, that was hairy!  Here is how I fixed problem for anyone doing anything similar.  Thanks Julien.

added these to class:

```
  ~log_stream() { if(fp_) fclose(fp_); }

  // this is the main one I was missing
  abc::log_stream& abc::log_stream::operator<<( log_stream& (*pf)(log_stream&) )
  {
     return pf(*this);
  }
```

Then outside class:

abc::log_stream& endl( abc::log_stream& log )
   {
      log.endl();
      return log;
   }

Comment: I see an `endl` member function in the `log_stream` class.  I see no `endl` entity declared top level in the `abc` namespace.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Somewhat off-topic - do you really want a logging stream with its own implementation?

Have a look at http://marcoarena.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/dont-couple-streams-with-devices/

Comment: After your update: Now see John's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::endl` is a function taking a `std::ostream` as its single parameter, and `ostream<<` is an overload which takes the type of `std::endl`.

To copy this behavior for your `log_stream`, override `std::endl` for it:

```
abc::log_stream& std::endl( abc::log_stream& log )
{
    log.endl();
    return log;
}
```

and override `abc::log_stream::operator<<` to use it:

```
abc::log_stream& abc::log_stream::operator<<( log_stream& (*pf)(log_stream&) )
{
    return pf(*this);
}
```

As you can see, the argument of `abc::log_stream::operator<<` takes the type of `std::endl` as argument.

Also, note that `std::endl` [flushes the stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl). Thus you should consider calling `fflush(fp_)` in `abc::log::endl()`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I did start on road to implementing the operator<<(function ptr bit - but was struggling.  Yes I realised about flush - is on todo list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make an `operator<<` that takes your `endl` type.  Or let it take `std::endl`.  See also this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1134467/4323 - basically, `endl` is a function like you have, but you need to make an insertion operator for your class that accepts that function as its right-hand argument, and invokes it.