# How pass std::endl to a function and use it?

Tags: c++, manipulators

I want to figure out how to pass a manipulator like `std::endl` to a function and then use the passed-in manipulator in the function. I can declare the function like this:

```
void f(std::ostream&(*pManip)(std::ostream&));
```

and I can call it like this:

```
f(std::endl);
```

That's all fine. My problem is figuring out how to use the manipulator inside `f`. This doesn't work:

```
void f(std::ostream&(*pManip)(std::ostream&))
{
  std::cout << (*pManip)(std::cout);            // error
}
```

Regardless of compiler, the error message boils down to the compiler not being able to figure out which `operator<<` to call. What do I need to fix inside `f` to get my code to compile?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134388/stdendl-is-of-unknown-type-when-overloading-operator

Comment: I don't think it's the same question. I don't want to create a custom manipulator, I just want to use an existing manipulator that's passed as an argument to a function.

Comment: just call (*pManip)(std::cout) inside

Comment: Just go `std::cout << pManip;`

Comment: `std::cout << pManip` will print the address of the function.  (`pManip` is a function pointer.) See Sveltely's answer for the proper code.

Comment: function pointers can be used this way too.So std::cout << pManip; should be ok. Indeed on your own code the problem was that you were passing result of  (*pManip)(std::cout) to <<(stream output function)

Comment: My mistake, you're right. Thanks for the education.

Comment: We all do such errs.It is cause of not being attentive. Being not attentive can lead such minor errors.Plus with c++ one should be a bit more attentive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void f(std::ostream&(*pManip)(std::ostream&))
{
  std::cout << "before endl" << (*pManip) << "after endl"; 
}
```

or

```
void f(std::ostream&(*pManip)(std::ostream&))
{
  std::cout << "before endl";
  (*pManip)(std::cout);
  std::cout << "after endl"; 
}
```

Comment: Note that a `const` function pointer is also permitted: e.g. `void f(std::ostream&(* const pManip)(std::ostream&))`.