# Variadic Template Functions: No matching function for call, std::endl

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

In my code, I use ***variadic template functions*** for the logging purpose. But when I use `std::endl` as parameter, I get the following compiler error:

> Error: no matching function for call to 'LOG_ERROR(const char [14],
>   int&, )'   LOG_ERROR("Sum of x+y
>   = ", z, std::endl);
>
> note: candidate: 'void LOG_ERROR()'  inline void LOG_ERROR() {
>
> note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided

*My Code:*

```
#include <iostream>

inline void LOG_ERROR() { 
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<typename First, typename ...Rest>
void LOG_ERROR(First && first, Rest && ...rest){
    std::cout << std::forward<First>(first);
    LOG_ERROR(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}

int main() {
    int foo=40;
    LOG_ERROR("My foo = ", foo, std::endl);
}
```

The code works fine with `"\n"` but I would love to learn why it fails with `std::endl` and how I can fix it

Comment: The issue is also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22927906/9593596). I don't think it's a duplicate though, as your question involves passing `std::endl` in parameter pack to be expanded?!

Comment: `std::endl` is a function template, not just a function. You're passing it without  deduction (either specific or deduced). If you populated the template to an actual function instantiation (such as `std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>`, it should work.

Comment: @WhozCraig The thing here is I won't be the user of the `LOG_ERROR` function but I would like the user to be able to use the function with `std::endl`.

Comment: @eneski I understand, but I don't know what to tell you. The problem is the context in which it is used.  There is no "there" there until such time as `std::endl` is used in a deducible context, which it isn't in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::endl` is not a character type or any other type. It is output stream manipulator. Its return type is output stream.

So, you can not pass it without typecasting. Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22927906/9593596)

Answer (score 8):

Long story short - `std::endl` is function template which template arguments can't be deduced while passing. You can help Your compiler this way:

```
LOG_ERROR("My foo = ", foo, std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>);
```

As much as I feel this is ugly piece of code it works perfectly.

Comment: `auto endl = std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>;` helps.

Comment: @YSC If I were to choose, I'd go with suggested somwhere down here: `auto endl = [](auto&&os) -> decltype(auto) { return os << std::endl; }`

Comment: Don't do this. It doesn't "work perfectly" - it's unspecified. The standard library reserves the right to break this code at any time - you should not take the address of or explicitly specify standard library functions/function templates. You have to use a lambda (or normal function object).

Comment: @Barry Good to know. Thank you.

Comment: @Barry Could You reference to standard? I never heard of such a restriction

Comment: @bartop [\[namespace.std\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std). I guess technically since `endl` is an addressable, non-member function template, it's safe in this case as covered by [\[global.functions\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/global.functions) but it's still nicer to just avoid it entirely.

Answer (score 7):

Until someone comes with a better solution, you can use a trivial wrapper with an appropriate operator overload:

```
struct EndlWrap {};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, EndlWrap) {
   return os << std::endl;
}
```

which should be usable like this:

```
LOG_ERROR("My foo = ", foo, EndlWrap{});
```

This has an advantage when your logging destination might be a non-standard stream, i.e., the template arguments of `std::endl` can still be deduced when it's `<<`'d into the stream.

Comment: Possibly: `auto EndlWrap = [](auto&&os) -> decltype(auto) { return os << std::endl; }`. it works also with `std::wcout`. (or templatize your function).

Comment: That's nice!! The question is tagged C++11, though.

Comment: So fallback to old functor class.

Comment: This would work, too: `auto EndlWrap = [](std::ostream& os) -> std::ostream& { return os << std::endl; };`

Comment: Right... functor class with a `<<` template seems to be the way to go then.

Comment: I meant `struct { template<typename OS> OS& operator()(OS& os) const { return os << std::endl; } } EndlWrapper;` (the "equivalent" of the lambda).

Comment: Hm, but that doesn't compile. The stateless lamdba converts to a function pointer, for which `<<` is overloaded, but that doesn't apply for the struct.

Comment: I so miss the `template <typename OS> operator OS& (*)(OS&)`... (and so replace const method by static one).

Answer (score 1):

You can use defaulted template parameters and defaulted function arguments instead of a variadic template.

The code is less clean and you will have to choose a limitation on the number of parameters, but it will do the job:

```
template<class...>
inline void LOG_ERROR_();
template<>
inline void LOG_ERROR_<>() { 
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
template<typename First, typename ... Rest>
void LOG_ERROR_(First && first, Rest && ...rest){
    std::cout << std::forward<First>(first);
    LOG_ERROR_<Rest...>(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
    //could be cleaner with if constexpr
}

using manip_t = std::basic_ostream<char>&(*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&);

std::basic_ostream<char>& no_manip(std::basic_ostream<char>& o){
    return o;
}

template<typename A=manip_t
  ,typename B=manip_t, typename C= manip_t
  ,typename D=manip_t // to be continued
  >
inline void LOG_ERROR(A&& a=no_manip, B&& b=no_manip,C&& c=no_manip
              ,D&& d=no_manip /*to be continued*/){
    LOG_ERROR_<A,B,C,D/*to be continued*/>(
       std::forward<A>(a),std::forward<B>(b),std::forward<C>(c),
        std::forward<D>(d)/*to be continued*/);
}
```

Depending on the compiler this code could produce ugly assembly. One solution is to write an overload for each possible number of argument, or have a good knowldge of compiler specific function attributes (always_inline,etc...)