# Inherit from std::ostringstream

Tags: c++, templates, stringstream

In my project I use a class class called Message which inherits from std::ostringstream to print out human readable information of other class types.

So its << operator is overloaded several times taking my own class types which I want to print out.

```
class Message : public ostringstream
{
public:
    Message() {};
    virtual ~Message() {};

    Message& operator <<(const MyTypeA &a) { return *this << a.getStr(); };
    Message& operator <<(const MyTypeB &b) { return *this << b.identifier(); };
    Message& operator <<(const MyTypeC &c) { return *this << c.foo(); };

    // Pass everything unknown down to ostringstream, and always return a Message&
    template<class T>
    Message& operator <<(const T &t)
    {
        (std::ostringstream&)(*this) << t;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Without the template

```
MyTypeA a,b;
Message m;
m << a << "-" << b;
```

the code would not compile, as (m << a << "-") would return a ostringstream& which would not be able to take 'b'. So I use the template to make sure to always return a Message&.

My Problem:

```
Message m;
m << "Hello, world" << std::endl;
```

generates a veeery long compiler error and I do not know why.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/cReX6YbU) is a minimalistic "not" compilable example of my problem, and [here](http://pastebin.com/KDfRFSr1) is the corresponding compiler output.

Comment: Here's the key part of the error: *couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’*

Comment: Why don't you implement `ostringstream& operator<<(ostringstream &os, const MyTypeA &a)` instead?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1134388/951890

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do **not** derive from any of the stream classes to create a new stream! The only reason to derive from `std::ostream` or `std::istream` is to create a stream properly set up to use a suitable stream buffer. Instead of deriving from a stream, you should derive from `std::streambuf` to create  a new source or destination. To create output operators for new types you'd overload `operator<<()` with `std::ostream&` as first argument and your custom type as second argument. Likewise with `std::istream&`.

BTW, the problem you encountered is because `std::endl` is a function template. Trying to pass a function template somewhere requires that the appropriate instantiation can be deduced. Since your output operators don't cover a suitable signature, the instantiation of `std::endl` can't be deduced. I could state what's needed but that would be pointless as it is the wrong way to go anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to make your code compile: http://pastebin.com/xAt5junf

The relevant excerpt:

```
class Message : public ostringstream
{
public:
    Message() {};
    virtual ~Message() {};
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream &os, const MyTypeA &a) {
    return os << a.getStr();
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream &os, const MyTypeB &b) {
    return os << b.getStr();
};
```