# std::endl is not working with overloaded operator<< though dedicated non template function is implemented

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, function-pointers, std, endl

I have some `Logging::Logger` class with the following functions:

```
template<typename T>
const Logger& Logger::operator<<(const T& in) const {
    // ...
    return *this;
}

const Logger& Logger::operator<<(std::ostream& (*os)(std::ostream&)) {
    // ...
    return *this;
}
```

And the following code:

```
loggerInstance << "ID: " << 5 << endl;
```

And I'm getting the following error though all operators seems to be implemented:

> error C2678: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'const Logging::Logger' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

Of course, without `endl` everything is working.

I've looked at the following answer:

[std::endl is of unknown type when overloading operator<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134388/stdendl-is-of-unknown-type-when-overloading-operator)

What am I missing?

Comment: Logging shouldn't require explicit flushing. That should be done internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your overloaded operators return a `const Logger &`, it follows that they must be `const` class methods, in order for you to be able to chain them together:

```
const Logger& Logger::operator<<(std::ostream& (*os)(std::ostream&)) const
```

However, it's better if they were not `const` class members, and returned a `Logger &`, instead:

```
template<typename T> Logger& Logger::operator<<(const T& in)

Logger& Logger::operator<<(std::ostream& (*os)(std::ostream&))
```

This would be because, presumably, `operator<<` would be modifying the `Logger` instance, in some way. If not, you can use `const` objects and methods, here.